# How do I get winner voter on pandas based on sorting algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Here's my data

```
No   Candidate_A    Candidate_B   Candidate_C
1              8              9            12
2             18              9            12
3              9              9             7
```

Here's the result what I want, the logic is `Candidate_A` is more than `Candidate_B`, `Candidate_B` wins, if not `Candidate_A`, basically it just sorting algorithm

```
No   Candidate_A    Candidate_B   Candidate_C     Result
1              8              9            12     Candidate_C     
2             18              9            12     Candidate_A
3              9              9             7     Candidate_A
```

Comment: `No` is column or index?

Comment: Column, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['Res'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(axis=1)
#if first column is index
#df['Res'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
   No  Candidate_A  Candidate_B  Candidate_C          Res
0   1            8            9           12  Candidate_C
1   2           18            9           12  Candidate_A
2   3            9            9            7  Candidate_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .idxmax function and then add a column:

```
import pandas as pd

candidates = pd.DataFrame({'Candidate_A': [8, 18, 9], 'Candidate_B': [9, 9, 9], 'Candidate_C': [12, 12, 7]}, index=[1, 2, 3])

candidates['Results'] = candidates.idxmax(axis=1)
print(candidates)
```

Here is your output:

```
           Candidate_A  Candidate_B  Candidate_C      Results
1            8            9           12             Candidate_C
2           18            9           12             Candidate_A
3            9            9            7             Candidate_A
```

As you know, you can add an additional column by using brackets ['Results'], 
and we will just set it equal to the max in each row with the idxmax function. Remember to set the axis to 1 if we are getting the max based on each row of data instead of each column of data.

Comment: Sorry, so what is difference with my answer?

Comment: No need for .iloc or a slicing in the situation.

Comment: It depends if `No` is column or not. If `No` is colum, yes

Comment: Did you originally use the default zero based index format?

Comment: Obviously yes. If not `No`  is in second row. So from sample data `No` is column

Comment: the main answer is the `idxmax` function